# How to improve performance on average calculations in python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to improve the performance of a current piece of code, whereby I loop through a dataframe (dataframe 'r') and find the average values from another dataframe (dataframe 'p') based on criteria.

I want to find the average of all values (column 'Val') from dataframe 'p' where (r.RefDate = p.RefDate) & (r.Item = p.Item) & (p.StartDate >= r.StartDate) & (p.EndDate <= r.EndDate)

Dummy data for this can be generated as per the below;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


######### START CREATION OF DUMMY DATA ##########

rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-10-28')
daily_range = pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-12-31')

p = pd.DataFrame(columns=['RefDate','Item','StartDate','EndDate','Val'])
for item in ['A','B','C','D']:
    for date in daily_range:
        daily_p = pd.DataFrame({ 'RefDate': rng,
                            'Item':item, 
                            'StartDate':date,
                            'EndDate':date,
                            'Val' : np.random.randint(0,100,len(rng))}) 
        p = p.append(daily_p)


r = pd.DataFrame(columns=['RefDate','Item','PeriodStartDate','PeriodEndDate','AvgVal'])
for item in ['A','B','C','D']:
    r1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'RefDate': rng,
                        'Item':item, 
                        'PeriodStartDate':'2019-10-25',
                        'PeriodEndDate':'2019-10-31',#datetime(2019,10,31),
                        'AvgVal' : 0}) 
    r = r.append(r1)
r.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

######### END CREATION OF DUMMY DATA ##########
```

The piece of code I currently have calculating and would like to improve the performance of is as follows

```
for i in r.index:

    avg_price = p['Val'].loc[((p['StartDate'] >= r.loc[i]['PeriodStartDate']) & 
                         (p['EndDate'] <= r.loc[i]['PeriodEndDate']) &
                         (p['RefDate'] == r.loc[i]['RefDate']) &
                         (p['Item'] == r.loc[i]['Item']))].mean()

    r['AvgVal'].loc[i] = avg_price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first change is that generating *r* DataFrame, both *PeriodStartDate* and
*PeriodEndDate* are created as *datetime*, see the following fragment of your
initiation code, changed by me:

```
r1 = pd.DataFrame({'RefDate': rng, 'Item':item,
    'PeriodStartDate': pd.to_datetime('2019-10-25'),
    'PeriodEndDate': pd.to_datetime('2019-10-31'), 'AvgVal': 0})
```

To get better speed, I the set index in both DataFrames to *RefDate* and *Item*
(both columns compared on equality) and sorted by index:

```
p.set_index(['RefDate', 'Item'], inplace=True)
p.sort_index(inplace=True)
r.set_index(['RefDate', 'Item'], inplace=True)
r.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This way, the access by index is significantly quicker.

Then I defined the following function computing the mean for rows
from *p* "related to" the current row from *r*:

```
def myMean(row):
    pp = p.loc[row.name]
    return pp[pp.StartDate.ge(row.PeriodStartDate) &
        pp.EndDate.le(row.PeriodEndDate)].Val.mean()
```

And the only thing to do is to apply this function (to each row in *r*) and
save the result in *AvgVal*:

```
r.AvgVal = r.apply(myMean2, axis=1)
```

Using *%timeit*, I compared the execution time of the code proposed by *EdH* with mine
and got the result almost 10 times shorter.

Check on your own.

Answer (score 0):

By using iterrows I managed to improve the performance, although still may be quicker ways.

```
for index, row in r.iterrows():      
    avg_price = p['Val'].loc[((p['StartDate'] >= row.PeriodStartDate) & 
                         (p['EndDate'] <= row.PeriodEndDate) &
                         (p['RefDate'] == row.RefDate) &
                         (p['Item'] == row.Item))].mean()

    r.loc[index, 'AvgVal'] = avg_price
```